# How do you slidetoggle a div while a yes or no radio is selected in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, slidetoggle

I haven't been able to find something that works or does what I'm looking for. I'm trying to toggle hide/show a div depending on a selected yes or no radio button. I have the following for the html

```
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="radio" value="1" /> Yes
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="radio" value="2" /> No
    <div id="more_questions">Data</div>
```

There is a lot more before and after this code in a form tag but this is the focus. The Javascript/jQuery is

```
$("#yes").click(function(){
    if($("#yes").is(':checked')){
        $("#more_questions").slideToggle();
    }
});
```

I have also tried checking to see if #yes.checked == true and that hasn't worked. I'm not sure what it is that I'm missing but if anyone could help I would really appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input[name=radio]").on('change', function(){
    $("#more_questions")[this.id=='yes'?'slideDown':'slideUp']();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/txSvg/)

Comment: This one seems to be more specific to a given radio button. Helpful when there are more than just 2 radio buttons. Thank you both j08691 and adeno for answering! Both answers worked great!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("input[name=radio]").click(function () {
    if ($("input[name=radio]:checked").val() == '1') {
        $("#more_questions").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#more_questions").slideUp();
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kqsd6/)**